# Load Images in Angular + Cordova App

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I got my Angular 5 app working with Cordova. The only problem is the images are not loading. The path I'm specifying looks like this:

```
/assets/img/logo.png
```

I use these paths for images:

```
<img class="logo-img" src="/assets/img/logo.png">
```

as well as inside the styles:

```
background: url(/assets/img/success-backg.png) no-repeat center center;
```

This is occurring for Android and iOS builds.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure to be able to use the absolute URL? Try using the `../` notation instead

Comment: Check if your cordova build staging folder has `www/assets`

Comment: @FrancoScarpa Thanks, will give it a try. I would expect Cordova do it though, making changes according to the target platform's requirements

Comment: @bhantol Yes it has the assets folder inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing '/assets/..'. with './assets/...'. I'm facing issues with building sass files with relative paths and at the moment have to do the replacement right inside the output files (after ng build --prod). Probably Angular CLI has some option for handling this too.

Comment: Relative paths are handled by CLI long ago. But recently a bug was resolved in 1.6.4 with respect to relative paths may help your case if you are not up to date.

Comment: For paths inside assets use a variable line there fontawesome example

Comment: Latest version, installed yesterday... This was the fix - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

any reference to a resource in your app that is not absolute you should add a "./" to the path, like

src="**./**assets/images/logo.jpg'